# zsh — ^W behavior with oh-my-zsh

Tags: command-line, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've recently started using ZHS with oh-my-zsh script pack. It does excellent job except of weird ^W shortcut behavior.

For example if I have following command line and symbol ▮ denotes cursor position.

```
$ ./command_name --option1 value --option2=value ▮
```

Sequentially pressing ^W for several times I'd get following content in command prompts:

```
$ ./command_name --option1 value --option2=▮
$ ./command_name --option1 value --▮
$ ./command_name --option1 ▮
$ ./command_name --▮
$ ./command_▮
$ ./▮
```

What bugs me is that after third press cursor stops not after deleting `--`, but also eats `value`. I suspect that all symbols such as "_-" are considered as separators as spaces and zsh continues eating symbols until it deletes some non-separator chars, but I have no idea how to change this behavior.

Comment: UPD: I've tried solutions from here, didn't help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444951/zsh-stop-backward-kill-word-on-directory-delimiter

Comment: What is `echo $WORDCHARS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to fix this (default) behavior you want to have Zsh use vi-style `backward-kill-word`.

Put this in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
bindkey '^W' vi-backward-kill-word
```

Now, it will kill to the following positions:

```
$ ./command_name --option1 value --option2=▮
$ ./command_name --option1 value --option2▮
$ ./command_name --option1 value --▮
$ ./command_name --option1 value ▮
$ ./command_name --option1 ▮
$ ./command_name --▮
$ ./command_name ▮
$ ./▮
$ ▮
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in your case `WORDCHARS` doesn't contain `-`, `_`, `.`, `/`, or `=`, from the line editor's perspective it looks like:

```
$   command name   option1 value   option2 ▮
$   command name   option1 value   ▮
$   command name   option1 ▮
$   command name   ▮
$   command ▮
$   ▮
```

In other words, `=`, `--`, `_`, and `./` are treated as white spaces.

Adding more word characters will not only fix `backward-kill-word` but all word-wise widgets, among which `copy-prev-word`, `transpose-words`, `up-case-word`, and many others.

It will also affect glob pattern expansion. For example, adding `+` makes `!" /bin/?[![:WORD:]]##` match `/bin/c++`, `/bin/g++`.